# Css Flex/ Start end/ aligning 3 components

Tags: css, styled-components

Hello I need a button that has 3 alignments

one icon on the left
a button in the middle and a button at the end of the div

```
    <Content>
        <Image src = { logo }  style = {{width:'50px'}}/>  
        <Button />    
        <Button />  
    </Content>
```

css:

```
export const wrapStyle = css`
    min-height: 55px;
    max-height: 55px;
    width:100%;  
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0 !important; `;

export const contentLogo = css`
    width:240px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(31,30,30,.12)!important;
    line-height: 52px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .3s; `;
```

like this:

[image]

I believe the best way would be with flex end start etc

I tried but couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: purple;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-item"> Item One </div>
  <div class="flex-item"> <h1>Item Two</h1> </div>
  <div class="flex-item"> Item Three </div>
</div>
```